# searching for existing data, double if php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a webpage and I want to have a possible delete button which works in the following manner:

```
 - you introduce a country ISO code which you want to delete
 - click the button
 - if the country has players participating (competitor table, ISO_country_code column) then prints the message that this cannot happen
 - if not, deletes the country from country table
```

I tried in the following way, but I don't know how to create the condition of the second if in order to achieve the appropiate working.

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 else 
 {
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM competitor
        WHERE ISO_country_code='".$_POST['countrycode']."')")
    if ($result>0)
    {
        echo 'The following country is involved with players, so it can not be deleted!</br></br>';
    }
    else (mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM country WHERE     ISO_country_code='".$_POST['countrycode']."'"));
    {
        echo 'The following country was deleted: '.$_POST["countrycode"]."</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: please note that `1'; drop table country; '"` in the post would be quite dramatic

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection in your code

Comment: That you might want to start using prepared statements instead...best SQL injection protection there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$result` is containing no integer, it returns true or false (or an object, when using the object-oriented way).

If you want to check how many results your query returns you have to replace your $result with the [mysqli_num_rows($result)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) function.

And you should take a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent SQL Injection.

First, you have to create a prepared statement of your query with:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect,"SELECT * FROM competitor WHERE ISO_country_code=?");
```

Then you bind the parameter to the statement (s stands for "String"):

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$_POST['countrycode']);
```

And execute your statement:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

You can then get the results for example with [mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors + probably didn't get nr of rows you were looking for.

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 else 
 {
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM competitor
        WHERE ISO_country_code='".$_POST['countrycode']."'");
     $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows>0)
    {
        echo 'The following country is involved with players, so it can not be deleted!</br></br>';
    }
    else {
      mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM country WHERE ISO_country_code='".$_POST['countrycode']."'");
        echo 'The following country was deleted: '.$_POST["countrycode"]."</br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a good point, however still enters the second if when it shouldn't.

Comment: @rafanadal how do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    echo "cannot delete";
    }
    else if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
     //write the query for deletion
    echo "deleted";
    }
```